# Класс для работы с изображениями

Tags: изображения, php

Всем привет.

Никак не могу найти хороший класс для загрузки, кропа и т.д... для изображений.
Проблема в том, что я очень слабо в этом разбираюсь.

Нашел мощный php_class_upload, но про него не лестные отзывы встречал.

Может есть что-то не сложное в понимании и с ImageMagick и с GD?
Кто что использует?

Comment: для кропа и подобного - imagemagick и gd хорошо работают. А вот для загрузки - это ищите отдельный класс. Хотя чем загрузка файла с картинкой отличается от просто загрузки файла?

Comment: обычная да, без проблем. я просто хотел готовый класс сразу, чтобы писать велосипеды для всего не имея достаточных знаний.

Comment: Здесь смотрели? http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1650-PHP-File-upload-handling-with-image-rescaling-support.html

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте библиотеку Intervention Image http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction

Работает как с imagemagick, так и с gd.

Comment: Ну да, ради 10 строк кода, брать тонну классов, и разбираться с ними неделю, для незнающего, а потом плюнуть, открыть оф сайт php и воспользоваться встроенным функционалом.

Comment: @And вопрос был в том, как несложно реализовать функционал и чтобы поддерживало и работу с GD, и с ImageMagick. Расскажите, как вы это готовы реализовать в 10 строк.

Comment: Откройте оф сайт `gd` и `ImageMagick` какие у вас возникли трудности использовать встроенные расширения?

Comment: @And попробуйте еще раз внимательно перечитать вопрос автора. Автор спрашивает о классе или библиотеке, позволяющей манипулировать изображениями без особых усилий из коробки, чтобы работало и с GD, и с ImageMagick. Таким образом, ваши комментарии абсолютно не соответствуют ни вопросу, ни ответу.

Comment: Что за чушь. Из коробки? Вы реально не понимаете о чем пишете. И коробки - это и есть из коробки, а не из тучи классов. написанными другими людьми